# Rails model naming partial acronym word

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, naming-conventions, acronym

So. For some reason I'm struggling with Rails naming today.  I feel like the best naming for a model I'm creating is DNSRecord for the camel case class model name and dns_record for snake case referencing -- Rails wants to name it DnsRecord.

I've seen a solution if the entire word is capitalized for example: API

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'API' 
end
```

but doesn't seem to work well as:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'DNSRecord' 
end
```

it still wants to refer to DnsRecord.  I know this is a small thing but DNSRecord feels better to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you will want `inflect.acronym 'DNS'` rather than `'DNSRecord'`. You will likely also have to restart your server after updating the inflections file.

Comment: that makes sense, trying now.